# Play Video on Iphone using code developed in html5

Tags: iphone, asp.net, html, video

I am playing videos through my asp.net application on desktops and mobile phones as well.

I have a code which is written in html using video tag. I send URL to user to play a video and it works totally fine on desktop's including Mac as well. I have tried accessing it on Samsung galaxy SII phone which has got android os in it. my video works on it with no issues but when I try to access that URL on iPhone player.aspx gets load properly but it just doesn't play the video.

Video is in .mp4 format.

I am playing it in IPHONE on safari browser.

Can anyone please help me regarding it.

Thank you